# Spawn and kill nodes from nodes/smach

Tags: roslaunch, smach, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a way to spawn/kill nodes from other running nodes or from smach SMs.

The roslaunch page makes it very clear that the roslaunch API is very unstable, which makes me afraid to use it. I've also found rosspawn tool, but its implementation is reportedly in proof-of-concept state and I see that the commits to it's repository stopped in October 2010.

Is there any recommended way to do this? Is using nodelets instead of regular nodes the best option?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9533/spawn-and-kill-nodes-from-nodes/smach/) by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1071 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-12-12**:
Great, thanks for the information!

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-12-08**:
I opened up a new similar thread w/o knowing this conversation was taking place half an year ago...anyways FYI: http://answers.ros.org/question/3225/terminate-launch-other-node-from-code some new ideas there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used roslaunch.scriptapi a while ago and it was doing its job:
http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roslaunch/html/roslaunch.scriptapi.ROSLaunch-class.html

You could also use the default python subprocess.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-03-23**:
Ok, I think I'll give it a try. Just to be sure I'm using it properly, is this correct? Create a Node instance -> create a ROSLaunch instance -> start the ROSLaunch instance -> launch the Node instance using ROSLaunch.launch and save the Process returned -> wait -> kill the node using Process.stop()